# offsetHeight returns 0 when rendering text into a div using a API

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a div which renders some text taken from a API call. I want to add a `See more` button if it
exceeds 3 lines. Following is my implementation for that.

```
         seeMore(){
            this.setState({
            seeMore: !this.state.seeMore
          })
         }
```

Inside render method

```
        function countLines() {
            var el = document.getElementById("about");
            var divHeight = el && el.offsetHeight;
            var lines = divHeight / 24;
            return lines;
        }
```

//above 24 is my line height.

Inside return

```
 <div>
       <div id="about" style={{WebkitLineClamp:seeMore ? '':3}}>
          {expert.bio}
       </div>
       {expert.bio !== undefined && (countLines() >= 3 && 
       <span onClick={this.seeMore.bind(this)}>{seeMore === true ? 'See less': 'See more'}</span>)}
 </div>
```

In the above solution my `offsetHeight` always returns a `0` even though there are content inside the div. I have set a condition to run the `countLines` function only when content is available. But still i get a `0` value for `offsetHeight`.

I have tried this solution with hardcoded values and then this works. It doesn't work only when rendering the text that is taken from a API.

Answer (score 0):

```
function countLines() {
        var el = document.getElementById("about").clientHeight;
        var lines = el / 24;
        return lines;
    }
```

You have tried this It will be worked.